# How to design dependency injection when external dependencies keep changing through object lifetime?

Tags: c++, dependency-injection, factory

I am designing a new class, let us call it SocketsManager. Its external dependency is Socket, an abstract class that specializes to SocketTCP or SocketUDP. SocketManager is a long running thread that manages system-wide socket opening, health, closing, etc.

```
class SocketManager {
    SocketManager(vector<Socket*> sockets);
    ~SocketManager();

    openSockets();
    closeSockets();

    vector<Socket*> sockets;
}
```

I plan to inject the vector of sockets via SocketManager's contructor.

Problem is the sockets change from time to time depending on system config. I might inject 5 sockets at construction, but some time later - due to config changes, my system needs 8 sockets. How do I pass in 3 more sockets now?

It makes me think then that the SocketManager should itself periodically monitor system config, determine socket requirements, and be able to request for more sockets.

This would then require a SocketFactory instead of constructor injection. But then I have to pass SocketFactory to SocketManager (instead of directly passing resources), have SocketFactory be either a singleton or have static method SocketFactory::getSocket() to avoid factory object instantiation, etc. These complicate the design, so I am trying to avoid if possible.

Any general wisdom? On how to handle DI with changing requirements?

Comment: You have the general idea right, but just make `SocketFactory` a `std::function<Socket*()>` instead, and let the injector worry about it being a singleton/object/function/whatever.

Comment: Thanks Frank, great idea! I went with function pointers for an elegant solution.